# Cursor finalized without prior close() in ListFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listfragment

I am getting this error message after I close the app or just let the phone sleep with the app open.

When I let the phone sleep, I get 30 to 61 log entries of this error message.  The error is logged just before the ListFragment is loaded.  I suspect the fragment gets loaded but the error is logged before fragment's info entries.

When I close the app, I only get 1 entry of the error which is logged just after the onLoaderReset() call.  I close the database before the app closes which appears to help.

The app works but I worry that it will fail once running on a variety of phones.

I do not explicitly control the cursor except for adapter.swapCursor(null) in onLoaderReset().

I appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this error.

Thanks

```
public class ChildList extends ListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, DatabaseConstants, GoodiList {

private final String TAG = "ChildList";

// database columns that we will retreive
final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { CHILD_ID_COLUMN,
        CHILD_NAME_COLUMN };

// selects all
final String SELECTION = null;

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;

private ListParent parentActivity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e(TAG, "on Create");
    String[] fromColumns = { CHILD_NAME_COLUMN, CHILD_ID_COLUMN };

    int[] toViews = { R.id.name_column, R.id.id_column };

    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.child_list_entry,
            null,
            fromColumns,
            toViews,
            0
            );

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    Log.i(TAG, "finished on Create");
}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    LongClickListener longClickListener = new LongClickListener();

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(longClickListener);
}

@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    Log.v(TAG, "starting on create loader");

    Uri CHILD_URI = ChildContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CHILD_URI,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);

    Log.v(TAG, "finished on create loader");

    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor newCursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);

    if (newCursor != null) {
        int rowCount = newCursor.getCount();

        Log.v(TAG, "--- onLoadFinished:  got " + rowCount + " children");
    }
}

/**
 * this used to delete. However, we need it to select usually. Now delete is
 * done by long click.
 */
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // delete child - remove child from list and database
    Object item = l.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) item;

    int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(CHILD_NAME_COLUMN);
    int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(CHILD_ID_COLUMN);

    final String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

    final int childId = cursor.getInt(idCol);

    Log.i(TAG, "selected " + name + " id: " + childId + " at position "
            + position);

    cursor.close();

    parentActivity.listItemSelected(this, position, childId);

}

/**
 * Forces cursor to requery database and list to be update. Used when a new
 * child is entered in parent activity's EditText field.
 */
public void notifyDataChanged() {

    Log.i(TAG, "told adapter that data changed");

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/** tell adapter that cursor is no longer valid*/
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
Log.i(TAG,"---- onLoaderReset -----");

adapter.swapCursor(null);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    parentActivity = (ListParent) activity;

    parentActivity.setList(this);

}
```

Comment: this is not error msg, it is warning...!!

Comment: though there should be some way of avoiding it.

Comment: @jeff-of-brooklyn Have you managed to find the answer? I'm struggling with the same problem right now.

Comment: I've mostly eliminated it by carefully closing the cursor. As Igotsar noted, it's a warning so it does not crash my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by taking a close look at the documentation.

According to the docs, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)

the method `swapCursor(Cursor data)` returns the original unclosed cursor. If the new cursor is the same as the old one or if there wasn't an old one, it returns null.

By changing my code from

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Cursor cursor = adapter.swapCursor(data);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

I stopped these warnings from appearing.

Note: You should do the same for `onLoaderReset()` method as well. For even when you do `adapter.swapCursor(null)`, it returns the old cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `changeCursor(Cursor cursor)` instead of `swapCursor(Cursor cursor)`

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)) you will see that it also closes the old cursor.